# Sorting Integers in Assembly

Tags: sorting, assembly, bubble-sort

Project is to create a bubble sort algorithm in assembly that will sort a given list of integers. I've got ascending down and my output is correct to some extent. It seems when combining the order of numbers gets mixed up, here's what I mean:

> 10 -20 5 12 30 -5 -22 55 52 0
>
> Number of integer = 10
> Ascend_or_Descend = 1
>
> 0 5 10 12 30 52 55 -22 -20 -5

Here's the code including the main method which was given to test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <io.h>

int sorter (int* list, int count, int opcode)
{
__asm
{
mov eax, 0          ; zero out the result
mov ebx, opcode     ; move opcode to ebx for comparison

mov ecx, count; //OuterLoop counter
cmp ecx, 1; //check length  
jle Return;  

OuterLoop:
   mov edi, list; //move in list    
   push ecx; 

   mov ecx, count; 
   dec ecx; //Decrement inner loop
InnerLoop:
   mov eax, [edi]; //First Value in list
   cmp ebx, 1; 
   je  Ascending; 
   cmp eax, [edi+4]; //next int is 4 bits away
   jb  Swap; 
   jmp Continue; 
Ascending:
   cmp eax, [edi+4]; //Again compare with next int
   ja  Swap; //if no swap
   jmp Continue; 
Swap:
   mov edx, [edi+4]; //Move to temp register
   mov [edi+4], eax; //Move stored value there
   mov [edi], edx; //Return temp value to list
Continue:
   add edi, 4; //Increment to move to next int
   loop InnerLoop; 
   pop ecx; //reset counter
   loop OuterLoop; 
Return:; 
}

}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
int numlist[1000], asc;
FILE *fptr;

int i = 0;

if (argc != 3)
{
    printf("Usage: %s filename asc_des\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
}

asc = atoi (argv[2]);
asc = (asc == 1) ? 1 : 2;

printf("\n");

fptr = fopen((argv[1]), "rtc");
if (fptr == NULL)
  printf( "File %s was not opened\n",argv[1] );
else
{
  /* Set pointer to beginning of file: */
  fseek( fptr, 0L, SEEK_SET );

  /* Read data from file: */
  while ( fscanf(fptr, "%d", &numlist[i]) != EOF )
  {
      printf( "%d ", numlist[i] );
      i++;
  }

  printf( "\n\nNumber of integer = %d\n", i );
  printf( "Ascend_or_Descend = %d\n\n", asc );
  fclose( fptr );
  }

  sorter( numlist, i, asc);

  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
      printf( "%d ", numlist[j] );

  printf("\n");

  return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Intel's manual:

> The terms “above” and “below” are associated with the `CF` flag and refer to the relation between two unsigned
>   integer values. The terms “greater” and “less” are associated with the `SF` and `OF` flags and refer to the relation
>   between two signed integer values

By using `jb` and `ja` you're treating the result of the comparison as the result of an unsigned comparison, hence why the signed numbers end up at the end of the sorted array (e.g. -22 when interpreted as an unsigned 32-bit value is 4294967274).

You should be using `jl` instead of `jb`, and `jg` instead of `ja`.

Comment: Sorry for late response but you were correct. New to this stuff, thanks!